# Apache ant - compile and run with build.xml

Tags: xml, apache, ant, build, build.xml

I want to compile and then execute my program, giving it 2 input parameters. Why doesn't it work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="run" name="MyProgram compile and run">

<target name="run" depends="compile"> 
    <classpath path="." />
    <exec executable="MyProgram">
        <arg value="80"/>
        <arg value="C:/"/>
    </exec> 
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="." destdir="." />
</target>

</project>
```

Comment: the classpath tag is not valid there.

Comment: Why not? My build file is in the same folder as my MyProgram.java. Or is it in a wrong position?

Comment: Classpath is for java and javac tasks, you can't use as nested tag of target.

Comment: **Don't make the source and destdir the same directory!** Create a _build_ directory of some sort and use that as a destdir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what are you trying to do? You're compiling a bunch of Java code, and then using `exec` to execute `MyProgram`. Is that file named `MyProgram.exe`? Or, is this Java code?

If `MyProgram` the java code you're compiling via the `javac`, you may need to use the `<java>` task which runs the Java Runtime Engine to execute the compiled `*.class` files.

I am going to assume you have a single Java file called `MyProgram.java`, and you want to compile it and execute `MyProgram.class`.

```
<project name="MyProgram" default="run" basedir=".">   <!-- No spaces in project name! -->

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/dest"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Put the Java Source and Destination under their own directories -->
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/dest"/>
        <javac srcdir="${basedir}/src"
            destdir="${basedir}/dest"/>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <!-- Assuming file called dest/MyProgram.class was built -->
        <java classname="MyProgram"
            classpath="${basedir}/dest">
            <arg value="80"/>
            <arg value="C:"/>
       </java>
    </target>
```